# Redirect after 5 seconds but only allow the page to be accessed by the referrer

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to have page1.php redirect to page2.php after 5 seconds. However page2.php needs to be a restricted page that can only be viewed if you are being sent from -->   mydomain.com/page1.php and can not be accessible if you type the address manually into the address bar.

I have tried methods that use shared keys, htaccess and php HTTP_REFERRER.

I believe the issue is coming from the redirection, and I believe it is because the redirect script is not sending the HTTP_REFERRER and therefore page2.php is looking at the url sent from the redirection script as being manually entered. I have tried with a simple php redirect and javascript. Below are the two different redirect scripts I have used.

php version.

```
header( "refresh:5;url=page2.php" );
```

Javascript version.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function Redirect() 
{  
    window.location="page2.php"; 
} 
setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);   
</script>
```

I have tried these with the full url and with/without http:// for example mydomain.com/page2.php.

Page2.php needs to only accept traffic from page1.php. I have no objection as to how to go about achieving this. Using shared keys or any other aspect just as long as the user can not enter the address manually and visit the page. I am also fully aware the Referrer can be spoofed however I do not have the expertise to get to advanced.

Comment: if I understand your question, YOU CAN USE SESSION OR COOKIES ....

Comment: Just a heads up: Headers can be spoofed, this is very weak "security".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use session data to make sure users of page2 have passed through page 1

With the way sessions work,The `encrypted string` is quite secure even if it is not encrypted at all.

on page1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['secret_key'] = 'encrypted_string';
```

on page2:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['secret_key'] == 'encrypted_string'){
   // user is authorized
   echo 'You are authorized to see this page';

}
else{
    echo 'Please visit page1 before accessing this page';

}

// Logic for authorized user
```

Or, shorter version for page2 :

```
if(empty($_SESSION['secret_key']) || $_SESSION['secret_key'] != 'encrypted_string'){
   die('You are not authorized to view this page.');
}

echo 'only authorized user will see from here forward';
```

BTW, when testing, remember that once your session is set, you will have to delete sessions in browser, or use incognito to test again.
To delete cache on chrome `ctrl+shift+delete` and choose cookies and other

Comment: Let me know if needs some tinkering, or if need extra encryption security

Comment: @Birdy BTW, when testing, remember that once your session is set, you will have to delete sessions in browser, or use incognito to test again.

Comment: You can also add `unset($_SESSION['secret_key'])` to the bottom of the page if you want to automatically deauthorize users after they view the page once.

Comment: @userbd nice touch! but maybe users don't need to be re authorized every time they reach the page

Comment: @Skarlinski, Excellent work.. It works without fault. Thank you for taking the time to help and im sure others in the same position will rely on your code in the future. I have done a small brief edit just to provide the slight modification i made that was perfect for my specific needs and just to put it out there for future viewers. Hope you receive the credit you deserve as i am limited +1 for you! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it, using 3 pages.

On the landing page, include your JavaScript, this will redirect you to an intermediate page that sets a session variable before redirecting to the final page.

On the final page, check the session variable, determine whether or not to display the page, then unset the session variable (so if they try again without returning to the first page, it will no longer work).

p1.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">   
function Redirect() 
{  
     window.location="p12.php"; 
} 
setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);   
</script>
```

p12.php

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['secret'] = 'todays_password';
$newURL = 'p2.php';
header('Location: '.$newURL);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">   
function Redirect() 
{  
     window.location="p2.php"; 
} 
Redirect();   
</script>
```

p2.php

```
<?php session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['secret']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['secret'] == 'todays_password')
    {
        //The user provided the correct secret session variable

        echo 'welcome. you can view this page.';
        //Put all of your page content here
        ?>

        <!-- HTML content should be in between php delimiters, like this-->

        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        //The user supplied a secret code, but it was not the correct one

        echo 'invalid secret.';

        //You can also add code for redirecting the user back to p1 here
        //Or just display an error message
    }
}
else
{
    //The user did not provide a secret session variable -- they most likely did not pass through p12.

    echo 'error, you are unable to view this page';

    //You can also add code for redirecting the user back to p1 here
    //Or just display an error message
}

unset($_SESSION['secret']); //This line makes the user return to p1 every time they visit p2 -- delete this line if you only want them to visit p1 once.
?>
```

To make this method secure, you'd need to give each user a unique value for their secret session variable. Store this variable, along with it's timestamp when the user visits p1 both as a session variable for the client and in a server-side database. When p2 is loaded, check to see if the session value they provide is at least 5 seconds old in the database. If it is, let them see the page. Then delete the value in the database.

Comment: I'm not sure why p12.php isn't redirecting correctly. It works for me. Do you have a hosted version somewhere? I've updated the code for p12 to add a JavaScript redirect as a failsafe in case the php redirect fails. 

My guess for why p2 would change is caching (since there's no dynamic content, there's no reason why anything would change). To restrict access to the page, you'd need to replace "echo 'welcome. you can view this page.';" with your page's content.

Comment: i have not had chance to re-try the above code yet. I modified Skarlinski's a slight amount and it worked perfectly and for that reason i accepted his answer. Im sorry i am not able to accept both answers as the top as you both really do deserve credit for taking your own time out to help and assist. I hope people see this in the future and give the +1 you both deserve. Thanks again and i will let you know tomorrow if there are any issues as its 2am and bed time for me now! Thanks